# Error in webconfig file "This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off"."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I got this Error while i deployed asp.mvc website.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

What i am missing?

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: maybe proxy in your browser or comment tags surrounding your entry (<!-- -->) ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your application DLL is in the right place on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, just for the record:

this error means that your application has crashed but the IIS server cannot show you the exact error because `customErrors` isn't `'Off'`.

to know about the error you can either recreate the error by browsing on your server's browser (localhost), or you can do `<customErrors mode="Off" />`.